# Bitcoin Cash split

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-cash

I have a bitcoin core wallet and held my bitcoins in this for around 5 years. Now I would like to access the bitcoin cash which I should have since the split. Is there a tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: This is an English language site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have Bitcoins in a local wallet, how do I get my Bitcoin Cash without using an exchange?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57351/i-have-bitcoins-in-a-local-wallet-how-do-i-get-my-bitcoin-cash-without-using-an)