# Is there a good guide to convert a Bitcoin Core Wallet to Bitcoin Cash (on OSX)

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, bitcoin-cash

I got a wallet in Bitcoin Core.app version 0.14.2 on OSX. My last transaction is from years ago. How can I convert my wallet to Bitcoin Cash and what are the do's and don'ts? Basically I don't want to loose my coins. I heard that I could claim both new coins, its that true and how to do so?

Comment: If you want to claim both coins, download both softwares from https://bitcoinclassic.com/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first paragraph in the answer to [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57351/i-have-bitcoins-in-a-local-wallet-how-do-i-get-my-bitcoin-cash-without-using-an) applies in your case (possible duplicate question?). As you run a full client (Bitcoin Core) it's easy, as Bitcoin Cash has equivalent apps which are forks of this. I used Bitcoin ABC.

I used a separate machine for the Bitcoin Cash wallet. It may be possible to run both on the same machine (with different data directories - see [this issue](https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/bitcoin-abc/issues/32)) but despite being called 'Bitcoin ABC.app' if you try and install it on the same machine as one with Bitcoin Core, you will get a message offering to overwrite the latter. Comments on how to accomplish this on one machine are welcome.

1. Backup Bitcoin Core wallet (`~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/wallet.dat`) to a USB stick (we'll transfer it later). This is the key **do**, which of course you will have done already
2. On the second machine download Bitcoin ABC from [bitcoinabc.org](http://bitcoinabc.org). Currently it is the `.dmg` file in the `osx` directory. I expect they'll improve the UX to have an easy Mac-specific download button soon.
3. To get the blockchain to sync either just run Bitcoin ABC until it does (it'll download a chain similar in size to the Bitcoin Core one i.e. - 150GB+) or copy the legacy part of the chain (common to both coins) from the Bitcoin Core data directory. As OP comments, a Time Machine or other backup is perfect for this. I'll update this answer if someone can comment on exactly how to do it without one, as ideally you'll need most of the contents of the `blocks` and `chainstate` directories - up until just before the fork date; 1 August. You'd then only need to sync since then.
4. Overwrite the new wallet.dat file Bitcoin ABC created (same location as above) with the one from step 1.
5. With both apps synced you should now be able to send/receive BTC/BCC *independently of each other* from the relevant app - i.e you now own both. Should you come down on one side of the fence & sell all of either you can of course remove it's app, data directory & return the spare/borrowed machine.

In terms of **dont's**, you should ignore any advice to export/mess with your *private keys* - especially is someone offers to claim your BCC coins for you if you send your keys..

Comment: thanx so far. As step 3 I think I can use my Time Machine backup from `~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/` from one of the last days of July as a start for the Bitcoin Cash blockchain.

Comment: Perfect solution

Comment: Thanx MatzFan, This worked almost prefect.
Unfortunately on OSX Bitcoin Core.app and Bitcoin ABC.app both use the same config file and therefore both want to use the same data directory.
As a workaround I created an new User and restored there. Then Bitcoin ABC.app was stuck at block 478558.
I found this page about it: https://www.reddit.com/r/btc/comments/6r64gx/bitcoin_abc_client_sync_stuck_at_478558/ I deleted peers.dat, that worked for me! (Thanx hugobits88)
Now I got both apps running on my Mac.
The only problem is that both want to use port 8333 so they can't run at the same time.