# claim bitcoin cash with bitcoin qt wallet

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I need to claim my bitcoin cash I held my coins in the bitcoin qt wallet from the spring on 2013 to the middle of aug. Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this done?
Thanks

Comment: Where did you store you bitcoin until November? You may be eligible for bitcoin gold too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57351/i-have-bitcoins-in-a-local-wallet-how-do-i-get-my-bitcoin-cash-without-using-an

Answer (score 1):

First of all, move your bitcoin to a new wallet. So it stays safe and secure.

Then download Electron Cash Wallet, create a new wallet and sweep the private key(s) of your old bitcoin-qt wallet.