# How to recover Bitcoin cash from Coinbase

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash, coinbase.com

I had a small bit of Bitcoin at Coinbase before the split. After the split, I moved a few Bitcoins to Coinbase, all of which were mined before the split. Now that Coinbase supports Bitcoin cash, they are only showing the small amount I had transferred before the split. The amount I transferred after the split but before they supported BCH is not showing up. I installed Bitcoin ABC and imported my BTC wallet and after synchronization, it shows 0 BCH. I can see the transaction to Coinbase in the transaction window. How do I recover the BCH? Is it even possible? I tried to contact Coinbase, but right now they are only answering account security and compromise related questions.
Thanks
Ali

Comment: Do you have timestamps? The fork occurred on [01.08.2017 at 12:16 UTC and on block #478558](https://support.coinbase.com/customer/portal/articles/2911542). You will not receive Bitcoin Cash for any Bitcoin you removed from the platform before the fork, or purchased/sent after the fork.

Comment: I had the coins in Bitcoin Core's wallet locally when the fork happened. I sent them to Coinbase after the fork.

Comment: In your case, Coinbase won't be able to help you. You will need to sweep the private key to the address where you stored the BTC when the fork happened. [Follow this guide](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57351/i-have-bitcoins-in-a-local-wallet-how-do-i-get-my-bitcoin-cash-without-using-an/57353#57353)

Comment: In the other topic, the user has the coins locally and wants to split the wallet. I have already send the coins to a BTC address. I tried to do something similar, but so far I haven't been successful. I installed Bitcoin ABC on a new drive and copied the data from my Bitcoin to Bitcoin ABC folder.  When I try to view the private key, I get an error message.  I have unlocked my wallet. The weird part is I can view really old transaction private keys, but not the new ones.